# How to display shipping rate in decimals while using Table Rate ( weight vs destination) in magento

Tags: magento

I want to display shipping price in decimal ($5.34) but table rate implementation rounding it off and displaying $5.00. Is there any way to display it correctly?

Thanks

Comment: I just did a test in my sandbox install of CE 1.6 and my table rate isn't rounding anything.  Can you export and post your shipping total from the admin?

Comment: maybe there is a problem with the csv file, so its not reading it properly?